# Why is my TensorFlow 2.1 tensor returned as "dtype=resource"?

Tags: tensorflow

I have created a tensor:

```
tensorX= tf.compat.v1.get_variable("tensorX", dtype=tf.float32,
                                        initializer = tf.compat.v1.constant(100.0))

#.....and when I read this tensor from the graph i.e.

graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()    
tensorXX = graph.get_tensor_by_name("tensorX:0")
print(tensorXX)

#Output
tensorX:0' shape=() dtype=resource
```

I have few related questions:

1. What is dtype=resource in tensorflow (version 2.1)?
2. While reading this tensor_by_name, why is it returning a "resource"?
3. Due to its "dtype=resource", I'm not able to assign some value to it. How should I read this tensor where "dtype=tf.float32" or how do I convert "dtype=resource" back to "dtype=tf.float32"?

Comment: Can you mention the tensorflow version you are using because in tensorflow 1.13.0 it is showing dtype as a float32

Comment: I am using version 2.1.

Comment: When i am trying on 2.1 it is not working throwing error of tensor does not exist in graph

Answer (score 0):

I just met this problem today when I tried to use freeze_graph in tensorflow2.5 to freeze a model with checkpoint. And I found the solution is to add these to the import sections in freeze_graph.py file:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
```

So, in your case, you can also try to add these two lines. Hope it helps.